# Configure nuget server to get packages from a specific azure location

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, nuget-server

I need a nuget server for our company's internal usage. I read about how to create a nuget server, and followed the steps and published my server to azure. I am able to upload my packages to the server through command prompt. Everything is working fine upto now as expected.

Now, as far as I know the packages will be stored in azure where my website is deployed. Now if the location of the cloud storage where my website is deployed changes, there is a possibilty that I will be losing all the packages pushed till then. So, to avoid this issue I would like to know if there is a possibility where I can configure the nuget server to look for packages from a cloud storage location which I know for sure will be there forever. Can this be done?

I am new to publishing websites to azure so if I was wrong in some of my assumptions above please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think its tricky  there was a package around that is out of date and UNC with authentication is a pain from web best option maybe a VM with plenty of disk..